# In ns-3, can ./waf --run a code in a nested folder more than two levels of folder?

Tags: waf, ns-3

3 and hope this question is not too stupid... I'm recently using ns-3 and try to compile the codes. I found that I don't need to explicitly specify compilation, instead, using

`./waf --run someCode.cc`

will first compile and code and then execute it. My question is, I'm trying to compile/run the code in a deeper folder. To be precise, I want to execute one example code located in

`<ns-3.22>/src/lte/example/lena-simple-epc.cc`

but when I enter

`./waf --run src/lte/example/lena-simple-epc`

I just got the following message:

```
Waf: Entering directory `..../ns-allinone-3.22/ns-3.22/build'
program 'src/lte/examples/lena-simple-epc' not found; available programs are: [...]
```

But, if I copy the file `src/lte/examples/lena-simple-epc.cc` under the folder `scratch` and execute `./waf --run scratch/lena-simple-epc`, then it works perfectly. Is this expected or did I miss any step? (Forgot to export some environment variables or something?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify all the path!

Just run:

`./waf --run lena-simple-epc`

If you are not secure on how to start a script just look at the wscript file in the examples folder and look for these rows.

```
obj = bld.create_ns3_program('lena-simple-epc',
                             ['lte'])
obj.source = 'lena-simple-epc.cc'
```

With *lena-simple-epc* you can start the script.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I finally solved my problem. I'd like to provide a little bit more detail though. (a) I didn't execute this command `./waf configure --build-profile=debug --enable-examples --enable-tests` before and thus cannot execute example code. (b) `./waf --run` is executed under the ns-3 root folder and waf will automatically such the path. (c) The quoted code in the second block is under <ns-3.22>/src/lte/example/wscript.